# как обеспечить соединение Asterisk 12 c GSM модемом

Tags: asterisk

В интернете находила множество статей о том как обеспечить взаимодействие 3g модема и Asterisk (в основном это предлагается сделать через модуль chan_dogle).
 Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно "подружить" Asterisk 12 c gsm модемом CINTERION mc52i?
В качестве операционной системы используется Ubuntu 14.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/bg111/asterisk-chan-dongle

В этой ссылке список модемов , и драйвер к ним, у меня уже 4 года работает на 3 серверах .